# Increase the Maximum string length of Excel PrintArea

Tags: vba, excel

I asked a question a while back about the Maximum string length of Excel Print Area :

[Maximum String Length of PrintArea in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6014807/maximum-string-length-of-printarea-in-excel)

Print Area is set at 255, for Excel 2010.

I think this is a read-only property but (clutching at straws here), is there any way to *Increase* the Print Area length? Excel plug-in maybe?

If not, I'll have to programmatically set a new print area, once the maximum 255 has been reached.

**EDIT:**

I've tried the answer below :

Range("A1:C3,A5:B6,C7:D8,E1:E2,G1:G2,A10:A11,A13:A14,A16:A17,A19:A20,A22:A23,A25:A26,A28:A29,A30:A31,A33:A35,A37:A38,A40:A41,A43:A44,A46:A47,A49:A50,A52:A53,A55:A56,A58:A59,A61:A63,A65:A66,A68:A69,A71:A72,A74:A75,A77:A78,A80:A81,A83:A84,A86:A87,A88:A89,A91:A92").Name = "MyNamedRange"

Works fine - 253 characters.

Range("A1:C3,A5:B6,C7:D8,E1:E2,G1:G2,A10:A11,A13:A14,A16:A17,A19:A20,A22:A23,A25:A26,A28:A29,A30:A31,A33:A35,A37:A38,A40:A41,A43:A44,A46:A47,A49:A50,A52:A53,A55:A56,A58:A59,A61:A63,A65:A66,A68:A69,A71:A72,A74:A75,A77:A78,A80:A81,A83:A84,A86:A87,A88:A89,A91:A92,A94:A95").Name = "MyNamedRange"

Run- Time error 1004 -(261 characters)

So, I guess now I should set multiple Named Ranges, then set the Active Sheet Print Area, using each named range in turn?

Thanks very much.

Comment: what is the reason you did not mark/accept the answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I broke the total Print Area into chunks of no more than 255 characters.

I exported each chunk into a separate excel row, then iterated through each row, setting the excel print area, and printing, as I went.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>cheat with named ranges:</strike>

`Range("A1:C3,A5:B6,C7:D8").Name = "MyNamedRange"`
then
`ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = "MyNamedRange"`

Seems there's a 255 character limitation on Named Ranges too.

next solution would be to hide the rows you don't want printed:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
    If ActiveSheet.Name = "Sheet1" Then
        Cancel = True ' cancel default print method so we can print out stuff ourselves
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        With ActiveSheet
            .Rows("12").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' hide the rows you want hidden
            .Rows("15").EntireRow.Hidden = True ' hide the rows you want hidden
            .PrintOut
            .Rows("12").EntireRow.Hidden = False ' unhide them after
            .Rows("15").EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End With
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: changed answer as Named Ranges have 255 char limit too

Comment: Thanks Sean - I think I will break my total Print Area string down into separate ranges each having 255 characters or less - then set the print area for each of these in turn..