# Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment

Tags: vba, debugging, excel

I'm having trouble debugging Error 450 in my code. With 17 ranges, the code is running fine, but when more ranges are added, it shows Error 450 Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment. Please have a look at the code. The first line is highlighted and 'Union' also when the error is displayed.

```
Sub Set_PrintArea()


Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim rng3 As Range
Dim rng4 As Range
Dim rng5 As Range
Dim rng6 As Range
Dim rng7 As Range
Dim rng8 As Range
Dim rng9 As Range
Dim rng10 As Range
Dim rng11 As Range
Dim rng12 As Range
Dim rng13 As Range
Dim rng14 As Range
Dim rng15 As Range
Dim rng16 As Range
Dim rng17 As Range
Dim rng18 As Range
Dim rng19 As Range
Dim rng20 As Range
Dim rng21 As Range
Dim rng22 As Range
Dim rng23 As Range
Dim rng24 As Range
Dim rng25 As Range
Dim rng26 As Range
Dim rng27 As Range
Dim rng28 As Range
Dim rng29 As Range
Dim rng30 As Range
Dim rng31 As Range
Dim rng32 As Range
Dim rng33 As Range
Dim rng34 As Range
Dim rng35 As Range


With Sheets("Performance")

    Set rng1 = .Range("$A$1:$U$13")
    Set rng2 = .Range("$B$15:$Z$52")
    Set rng3 = .Range("$B$55:$Z$92")
    Set rng4 = .Range("$B$95:$Z$132")
    Set rng5 = .Range("$B$135:$Z$172")
    Set rng6 = .Range("$B$175:$Z$212")
    Set rng7 = .Range("$B$215:$Z$252")
    Set rng8 = .Range("$B$255:$Z$292")
    Set rng9 = .Range("$B$295:$Z$332")
    Set rng10 = .Range("$B$335:$Z$372")
    Set rng11 = .Range("$B$374:$Z$407")
    Set rng12 = .Range("$B$410:$Z$443")
    Set rng13 = .Range("$B$446:$Z$479")
    Set rng14 = .Range("$B$482:$Z$515")
    Set rng15 = .Range("$B$518:$Z$551")
    Set rng16 = .Range("$B$554:$Z$587")
    Set rng17 = .Range("$B$590:$S$610")
    Set rng18 = .Range("$B$613:$V$642")
    Set rng19 = .Range("$B$650:$U$662")
    Set rng20 = .Range("$B$664:$Z$701")
    Set rng21 = .Range("$B$704:$Z$741")
    Set rng22 = .Range("$B$744:$Z$781")
    Set rng23 = .Range("$B$784:$Z$821")
    Set rng24 = .Range("$B$824:$Z$861")
    Set rng25 = .Range("$B$864:$Z$901")
    Set rng26 = .Range("$B$904:$Z$941")
    Set rng27 = .Range("$B$944:$Z$981")
    Set rng28 = .Range("$B$984:$Z$1021")
    Set rng29 = .Range("$B$1023:$AD$1066")
    Set rng30 = .Range("$B$1069:$AD$1112")
    Set rng31 = .Range("$B$1115:$AD$1158")
    Set rng32 = .Range("$B$1161:$AD$1204")
    Set rng33 = .Range("$B$1207:$AD$1250")
    Set rng34 = .Range("$B$1253:$AD$1296")
    Set rng35 = .Range("$B$1299:$S$1323")


    With .PageSetup
        .PrintArea = Union(rng1, rng2, rng3, rng4, rng5, rng6, rng7, rng8, rng9, rng10, rng11, rng12, rng13, rng14, rng15, rng16, rng17, rng18, rng19, rng20, rng21, rng22, rng23, rng24, rng25, rng26, rng27, rng28, rng29, rng30, rng31, rng32, rng33, rng34, rng35).Address
        .Orientation = xlLandscape
        .Zoom = False
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
        .FitToPagesTall = 1
    End With

    .PrintPreview

End With


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would seem this issue is a string character limit of 255 characters for `PrintArea`.  [See this Q](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11410374/445425)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have hit two limits in Excel: maximum parameters for `Union` (as others have said) and the string length limit for `PrintArea` of 255 characters.

Your print area address is < 255 long if you don't use absolute addressing

Try this

```
Sub Demo()
    ReDim rng(1 To 35)
    Dim rngPrintArea As Range
    Dim i As Long
    With Sheets("Performance")
        Set rng(1) = .Range("$A$1:$U$13")
        Set rng(2) = .Range("$B$15:$Z$52")
        Set rng(3) = .Range("$B$55:$Z$92")
        Set rng(4) = .Range("$B$95:$Z$132")
        Set rng(5) = .Range("$B$135:$Z$172")
        Set rng(6) = .Range("$B$175:$Z$212")
        Set rng(7) = .Range("$B$215:$Z$252")
        Set rng(8) = .Range("$B$255:$Z$292")
        Set rng(9) = .Range("$B$295:$Z$332")
        Set rng(10) = .Range("$B$335:$Z$372")
        Set rng(11) = .Range("$B$374:$Z$407")
        Set rng(12) = .Range("$B$410:$Z$443")
        Set rng(13) = .Range("$B$446:$Z$479")
        Set rng(14) = .Range("$B$482:$Z$515")
        Set rng(15) = .Range("$B$518:$Z$551")
        Set rng(16) = .Range("$B$554:$Z$587")
        Set rng(17) = .Range("$B$590:$S$610")
        Set rng(18) = .Range("$B$613:$V$642")
        Set rng(19) = .Range("$B$650:$U$662")
        Set rng(20) = .Range("$B$664:$Z$701")
        Set rng(21) = .Range("$B$701:$Z$741")
        Set rng(22) = .Range("$B$744:$Z$781")
        Set rng(23) = .Range("$B$784:$Z$821")
        Set rng(24) = .Range("$B$824:$Z$861")
        Set rng(25) = .Range("$B$864:$Z$901")
        Set rng(26) = .Range("$B$904:$Z$941")
        Set rng(27) = .Range("$B$944:$Z$981")
        Set rng(28) = .Range("$B$984:$Z$1021")
        Set rng(29) = .Range("$B$1023:$AD$1066")
        Set rng(30) = .Range("$B$1069:$AD$1112")
        Set rng(31) = .Range("$B$1115:$AD$1158")
        Set rng(32) = .Range("$B$1161:$AD$1204")
        Set rng(33) = .Range("$B$1207:$AD$1250")
        Set rng(34) = .Range("$B$1253:$AD$1296")
        Set rng(35) = .Range("$B$1299:$S$1323")

        Set rngPrintArea = rng(1)
        For i = 2 To 35
            Set rngPrintArea = Union(rngPrintArea, rng(i))
        Next

        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = rngPrintArea.Address(False, False)
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, @chrisneilsen. The code works fine except for one issue. It only prints up to rng(26). What can be done?

Comment: It would seem I was wrong: the `Range.Address` property apears to be truncated at a contiguous range boundary < 255.  Your whole range address even without the `$`'s is in fact > 255 characters.  I think you are out of options.  The link I posted in a comment to your Q suggests printing parts of the range in a loop, maybe you could try that?

Comment: I see. I tried going through that link you gave, but me being no expert didn't understand any of it. Anyway, thanks for your help. I'll have to split the range into different sheets maybe.

Comment: The idea in that link is to set the print area to a range (say your ranges 1..10), print that, then set the print another area (say your ranges 11..20).  Continue like that until all areas are printed.

Answer (score 3):

According to msdn, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834621(v=office.14).aspx

`Union` can only accept 30 parameters

Syntax

`expression .Union(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3, Arg4, Arg5, Arg6, Arg7, Arg8, Arg9, Arg10, Arg11, Arg12, Arg13, Arg14, Arg15, Arg16, Arg17, Arg18, Arg19, Arg20, Arg21, Arg22, Arg23, Arg24, Arg25, Arg26, Arg27, Arg28, Arg29, Arg30)`

To overcome this, you can split that 35 ranges into 2 sets.
e.g.

```
union1 = union(rng1, rng2, ... , rng30)
union2 = union(rng31, rng32, ... , rng35)
unionFinal = union(union1, union2)
```

Comment: Oh! Is there any way I can print all the 35 ranges? @sam092

Comment: @Raul try to split that into 2 sets and then apply union again (like what I do in my answer). Does that help?

Comment: 'unionFinal = Union(union1, union2)


        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = Union(unionFinal).Address
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With'
This is how the code looks and now the error is 'Argument not optional' highlighting Union in pageSetup.

Comment: @raul It should be with .PageSetup .PrintArea = unionFinal.Address

Comment: Yes, I corrected it and then I'm getting Error 424: Object required, highlighting 'unionFinal = Union(union1, union2)' @sam092

Comment: this is not the full code.....anyways, as suggested by the others, your range is too large

Answer (score 1):

Shorter...

```
Sub Set_PrintArea()

Dim rng As Range, x As Long, arr

    'add all your ranges here...
    arr = Array("$A$1:$U$13", "$B$15:$Z$52", "$B$55:$Z$92", "$B$95:$Z$132")

    With Worksheets("Performance")

        Set rng = .Range(arr(LBound(arr)))
        For x = LBound(arr) + 1 To UBound(arr)
           Set rng = Application.Union(rng, .Range(arr(x)))
        Next x

        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = rng.Address
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
        End With

        .PrintPreview

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: It is showing the Run-time error 1004: Unable to set the PrintArea property of the PageSetup class.

Could it be because of the huge range? @TimWilliams

Comment: Looks like `Address()` maxes out around 256 characters: the range is built correctly, but you can't get its address.